# Is it possible to use powerline adapters behind UPS's?

Tags: networking, bandwidth, ups

Currently i have my router connected in the 1st floor (with some switches), which is also connected with a 1200Mbps (real bandwith is about 600Mbps) powerline adapter.
Another powerline adapter is in my basement; also the main server is there.

I have bought two UPS devices (one for the router and the main switch, one for the server), which should provide power in case of a power failure.

- Since the powerline adapters require power to run, is it possible, to use them *behind* each UPS?
- If it is possible, how does this affect the bandwith?

If relevant: The powerline devices are "TP-Link AV1200".

Comment: Did you try connecting the powerline adapter av1200 to ups? Did it work? Was there any reduction in throughput? I'm asking since I'm planning to get a powerline adapter, while I already have the main router connected to the ups and planning to connect the av600 also to another ups so that internet doesn't drop everytime power drops.

Comment: @livinston Hey, that topic is like 4 years old ... Well, yes, I bought some if the 1200s, checked the connection both in front and behind the UPS and ... well, the UPS almost filters out everything of the powerline signals. I actually was able to establish a connection, but the throughput was like 50 kbit.

Comment: I ended up modifying two adapters, so they got their "own" power from the UPS, but don't do this when you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks. I also bought one and tried connecting between two different UPS and the connection was pretty much non-existent. Looks like I will have to live with internet dropping when power goes off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might work, but [almost](https://bt.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10694/~/do-powerline-adapters-work-with-anti-surge-power-strips%3F) [every](https://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-406.html) [manufacturer](https://kb.netgear.com/20233/Product-FAQ-Powerline-Adapters) warns against it.

From Netgear:

> Can I plug my powerline adapter into a power strip, surge protector,
>   Uninterruptible Power upplies (UPS) or extension cord?
>
> No. NETGEAR does not recommend using power strips, surge protectors,
>   UPS and extension cords with Powerline products.  These devices filter
>   out some or all of the high frequency signals used in Powerline
>   communications. Connecting a Powerline to one of these devices can
>   greatly reduce the data rate of transfers, or block communications
>   entirely.

From Tp-Link:

> Q: Can Powerline adapters work if they are separated by UPS?
>
> A: No. Usually, UPS  has filter function. It can cut the powerline
>   connection. Some air-switches or breaker also have the same function.
>   Besides, some power outlets have surge protector function which can
>   also cut the powerline connection. You’d better not plug powerline
>   adapters to outlets.

I should add that I'm using them with power-strips, and that's also not recommended, but it works and I don't have other option for now. So, I would say you should try and find out. It won't (or shouldn't) damage the devices (keep in mind though, that I'm not taking responsibility if it does!).

Comment: Hm, seems like i have to try it... Which "power-strips" do you use?